# C# searching through list

Tags: c#, list

I just started C# and I'm wondering what are the ways to use a list. Say I have a class

```
    class Node
    {
       field1;
       field2;

       method1()
    }
```

and a code

```
    List<Node> N;
```

What can I do to:

1. Go through each member of the list searching for a specific value. Say search so that field1 = 24
2. When found, call method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ to do that pretty simply:

```
foreach(var node in N.Where(n => n.field1 == 24)) {
  node.method1();
}
```

Comment: what's the n stands for?

Comment: The lambda expression in the `Where` clause is a shorthand way of writing a method.  The `n` is the parameter to that method.
  `bool Is24(Node n) { return n.field1 == 24; }`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `foreach` statement for this purpose

```
foreach(var node in nodes)
    if(node.field1==24)
        node.method1();
```

where `nodes` is `N` for you.

Another way it would be to use `LINQ`

```
nodes.Where(x=>x.field1==24).ForEach(x=>x.method1());
```

Last but not least, you could filter your list and then iterating through the elements of your list, you could call your method.

```
var filteredNodes = nodes.Where(x=>x.field1==24);

foreach(var node in filteredNodes)
    node.method1();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ForEach()` method, which performs the specified action on each element of the List.

```
N.ForEach(x => { if (x.field1 == 24) { x.method1(); } });
```

Comment: That's inefficient if `Where` returns many items. What's wrong with a simple `foreach`?

Comment: Better, yes, but imho it's more readable what cahinton has posted. I use `List.ForEach` rarely, only if i need to modify the list during enumeration.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks. Yes, I agree with you. But, I have newly started to use LINQ. And it seems really nice for me. But, it seems that I must  also think about efficiency.

Comment: `List.ForEach` is not even LINQ, it's a method that exists since .NET 2. So currently your answer contains no LINQ at all. (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 0):

use LINQ:

```
var results = N.Where(node => n.field1 == 24);

foreach(var result in results)
{
    result.method1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try something like this

```
var foundN  = N.Where(n=>n.field1=24); 
foreach( Node node in foundN)   
    Method(); 
//  or 
//   node.Method();
```